# No se envian datos por post en php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola amigos mi problema es bien sencillo

tengo esto en mi formulario html que envio a traves del form con metodo post

```
<form method="post" action="../Clase/RegistroCrud.php">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Rut</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TxtRut" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nombre y Apellido</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TxtNombre" placeholder="Pedro Gutierrez" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Numero de telefono</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="TxtNumTel" placeholder="+569 123456789" value="">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Persona a Quien Visita</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TxtPersVis" placeholder="Juan Valdez">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Area de visita</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option id="1">1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Hora de entrada</label>
                        <input type="datetime" class="form-control" name="txtHoraIn" value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y G:i');?>">

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Hora de salida</label>
                        <input type="datetime" class="form-control" name="txtHoraOut" value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y G:i');?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>¿Entrega Tarjeta?</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rbt" id="S" value="rdbSi" onclick="Show('DivsPrueba')"  checked value="S">Si</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="rbt" id="N" value="rdbNo" onclick="hide('DivsPrueba')" value="N">No</label>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" >
                    <div class="form-group" id="DivsPrueba" >
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Numero de tarjeta </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtNumTarj" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="btnGuardar" value="Guardar">
    </form>
```

Y esto en mi registroCrud.php

```
<?php

   include "../Conexion/conex.php";

   openConx();

   $Rut = $_POST['TxtRut'];
   $nombre= $_POST['TxtNombre'];
   $PersVis= $_POST["TxtPersVis"];
```

bueno asi con todo los inputs, el tema es que me da el siguiente error

> Notice: Undefined index: TxtRut in C:\xampp\htdocs\RegistroSistema\Clase\RegistroCrud.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined index: TxtNombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\RegistroSistema\Clase\RegistroCrud.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined index: TxtPersVis in C:\xampp\htdocs\RegistroSistema\Clase\RegistroCrud.php on line 14

Comment: Los for deben hacer referencia a los "name" de los inputs a los que pertenece. Y no pongas value="".

Comment: ¿Te llegan con $__REQUEST?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que tu ACTION está correcto?

Comment: Podés ver lo que estas recibiendo en RegistroCrud.php por POST mediante el código: echo var_dump($_POST);

Comment: y donde se muestra la consulta sql no la veo si lo pusiste ? y no colocaste el codigo completo del crud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica tus parámetros que estás recibiendo

```
if (isset($_POST["TxtRut"]) && !empty($_POST["TxtRut"])) {
    echo $_POST["TxtRut"];    
}else{  
    echo "no hay datos para mostrar";
}
```

Comment: No estoy recibiendo los parámetro a través de post, llegan null por ende no se hace el insert en la base de datos, lo que si a traves de get funciona

Comment: Aun así yo te recomiendo que siempre valides los datos que el usuario introduce, tanto en el lado del cliente (usando javascript o jQuery, por ejemplo) como en el lado del servidor, en este caso PHP. Simplemente es por motivos de seguridad

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo, lo pondre en practica